# Repeating "Events" (Calendar)

Tags: events, date, calendar

I'm currently working on an application that allows people to schedule "Shows" for an online radio station.

I want the ability for the user to setup a repeated event, say for example:-

"Manic Monday" show - Every Monday From 9-11
"Mid Month Madness" - Every Second Thursday of the Month
"This months new music" - 1st of every month.

What, in your opinion, is the best way to model this (based around an MVC/MTV structure).

Note: I'm actually coding this in Django. But I'm more interested in the theory behind it, rather than specific implementation details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, repeated events - one of the banes of my life, along with time zones. Calendaring is *hard*.

You *might* want to model this in terms of [RFC2445](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445). However, that may well give you far more flexibility - and complexity than you really want.

A few things to consider:

- Do you need any finer granularity than a certain time on given dates? If you need to repeat based on time as well, it becomes trickier.
- Consider date corner cases such as "the 30th of every month" and what that means for leap years
- Consider time corner cases such as "1.30am every day" - sometimes 1.30am may happen twice, and sometimes it may not happen at all, due to daylight saving time
- Do you need to share the schedule with people in other time zones? That makes life trickier again
- Do you need to represent the number of times an event occurs, or a final date on which it occurs? ("Count" or "until" basically.) You may not need either, or you may need one or both.

I realise this is a list of things to think about more than a definitive answer, but I think it's important to define the parameters of your problem before you try to work out a solution.

Comment: Some great comments... even if not a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

From reading other posts, Martin Fowler describes recurring events the best.
http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf

Someone implemented these classes for Java.
http://www.google.com/codesearch#vHK4YG0XgAs/src/java/org/chronicj/DateRange.java

Answer (score 0):

I've had a thought that repeated events should be generated when the original event is saved, with a new model. This means I'm not doing random processing every time the calendar is loaded (and means I can also, for example, cancel one "Show" in a series) but also means that I have to limit this to a certain time frame, so if someone went say, a year into the future, they wouldn't see these repeated shows. But at some point, they'd have to (potentially) be re-generated.

Comment: You'd normally cancel/change one event in a recurrence using an "exception" event.

Comment: Hmm.. hadn't thought about that!